# What are the best data structures(like hash map/list etc) to use for the following scenario

Tags: java, list, data-structures, hashmap

I have a requirement like there is an item A that has several sub items like a1,b1,c1... and each sub-item has in turn several sub-items like {a11,a12,a13...} which correspond to a1 and {b11,b12,b13..} which correspond to b1. So, its basically like a tree structure with item A as the root. Now, there is some time-stamp associated with each item and its sub-items. The time-stamp is different for all these items and sub-items. I need to find the item/sub-item with the latest time-stamp. How to proceed to solve this in java. Im kind of new to using data structures.

Comment: If it's `basically like a tree structure`, why not use a tree structure?

Comment: @azodious: Yes, we have item B,C... and sub items for them too

Comment: @SuryaChandra: Check my answer below. You can have a linked list for item B, C ... also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

It will suit your need. Here is a sample program from java.samples.com

```
// Create a tree map 
TreeMap tm = new TreeMap(); 
// Put elements to the map 
tm.put("John Doe", new Double(3434.34)); 
tm.put("Tom Smith", new Double(123.22)); 
tm.put("Jane Baker", new Double(1378.00)); 
tm.put("Todd Hall", new Double(99.22)); 
tm.put("Ralph Smith", new Double(-19.08)); 
// Get a set of the entries 
Set set = tm.entrySet(); 
// Get an iterator 
Iterator i = set.iterator(); 
// Display elements 
while(i.hasNext()) { 
Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next(); 
System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": "); 
System.out.println(me.getValue()); 
} 
System.out.println(); 
// Deposit 1000 into John Doe's account 
double balance = ((Double)tm.get("John Doe")).doubleValue(); 
tm.put("John Doe", new Double(balance + 1000)); 
System.out.println("John Doe's new balance: " + 
tm.get("John Doe"));
```

Answer (score 1):

For data structures, take a look at `java.util.TreeMap` for a tree-backed Map implementation, and `java.util.TreeSet` for a tree-backed Set implementation. These are standard implementations found in the Java Collections API.

```
package com.mindprod.example;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import static java.lang.System.out;

/**
 * Example use of java.util.TreeMap.
 *
 * @author Roedy Green, Canadian Mind Products
 * @version 1.0 2010-02-25 initial version
 * @see TestHashMap
 * @since 2010-02-25
 */
public final class TestTreeMap
{
// --------------------------- main() method ---------------------------

/**
 * Sample code to TEST TreeMap.
 *
 * @param args not used
 */
public static void main( String[] args )
    {
    // create a new HashMap
    TreeMap<String, String> t = new TreeMap<String, String>( /* no size estimates needed */ );
    // add some key/value pairs to the TreeMap
    t.put( "WA", "Washington" );
    t.put( "NY", "New York" );
    t.put( "RI", "Rhode Island" );
    t.put( "BC", "British Columbia" );
    t.put( "NC", "North Carolina" );
    t.put( "NE", "Nebraska" );
    // look up a key in the TreeMap
    String stateName = t.get( "NY" );
    // prints "New York"
    out.println( stateName );
    out.println( "enumerate all the keys in the TreeMap, by key" );
    // keySet gives you a Set, which is not a List.
    // If you need something you can sort, use toArray.
    // If you need a List, then use Arrays.asList.
    for ( String key : t.keySet() )
        {
        String value = t.get( key );
        // prints lines of the form NY New York
        // in key order, unlike a HashMap
        out.println( key + " " + value );
        }
    out.println( "enumerate all the values in the TreeMap, by key, note values out of order" );
    // values gives you a Collection which is not a List.
    // If you need something you can sort, use to Array.
    // If you need a List, then use Arrays.asList.
    for ( String value : t.values() )
        {
        // prints lines of the form New York
        // in key order, unlike a HashMap
        out.println( value );
        }
    out.println( "enumerate all the key/value Entries in the TreeMap, by key" );
    // This gives you a Map of Entry items. This is not suitable for sorting.
    for ( Map.Entry<String, String> entry : t.entrySet() )
        {
        // prints lines of the form NY=New York
        // in key order, unlike a HashMap
        out.println( "as Entry: " + entry );
        // this does not require an expensive get lookup to find the value.
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();
        out.println( "separately: " + key + " " + value );
        }
    out.println( "extract the keys into an array" );
    // actual type is a private nested static class TreeMap.KeySet
    // This Set is not Serializable.
    Set<String> justKeys = t.keySet();
    // Use toArray that takes an skeleton String[] array,
    // otherwise we end up with a useless Object[] instead of a String[].
    final String[] keys = justKeys.toArray( new String[ justKeys.size() ] );
    out.println( "extract values into an array, may contain duplicates unlike a Set." );
    // the actual type is a private nested static class TreeMap.Values
    // This Collection is not Serializable.
    final Collection<String> justValues = t.values();
    final String[] values = justValues.toArray( new String[ justValues.size() ] );
    out.println( "extract key/value pair entries into an array." );
    final Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> justEntries = t.entrySet();
    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" ) final Map.Entry<String, String>[] keyValuePairs =
            justEntries.toArray( new Map.Entry[ justEntries.size() ] );
    // Infuriatingly, this generates an unchecked conversion warning message.
    // Type erasure won't let us say:
    // Map.Entry<String, String>[] keyValuePairs =
    // justEntries.toArray ( new Map.Entry<String,String>[justEntries.size()] );
    // There might be some clever way of using Class.asSubclass to mollify the compiler.
    // There so many times when generics create more problems than they solve.
    }
}
```

You may also be interested in this [link](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2006/05/java-data-structure-generic-tree.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a decent tree structure implemented in the JDK.

Have a look at `TreeModel` and `TreeNode`, which are designed to be used with a `JTreePanel` but there is nothing stopping you from using it outside of Swing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, there is not item B:

1. Store item A, item B, item C ... in a linked list. (each node becomes a root)
2. item A will have following children nodes: a1, b1, c1 ... in a linked list. (each node becomes a root)
3. a11, a12, a13 can be stored as child nodes of a1.
4. Similar for b11, b12, b13 ...

Now, where are you facing problem?

Comment: There is item B,C... and sub items for them also

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create a Class for Item, then you can design the class separately.

For subitems depends on the data types, choose different data structures.
First if you know that items are of same types, for example a1, b1, c1 are all string then you can use ArrayList to hold them, or use array if the total number is bounded. If they are of different types, consider hashmap then.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use an array

```
ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
ArrayList sublist=new ArrayList();
ArrayList subsublist=new ArrayList();
subsublist.add("cat");
sublist.add(subsublist);
list.add(sublist);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider every item as a Node. So make a class Node. This class will have following members -
nodeName, parentNode, childNode.

```
public class Node
  {
    private String name;
    private Node parentNode;
    private Node childNode;
  }
```

Add additional attributes according to your use.

Write the constructor to create a Node object as below -

```
public Node(String name)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.parentNode = null;
    this.childNode = null;
  }
```

You will need to generate getters and setters for them to get the parent and child nodes associated.

I have not tested the code. Please re-fornat it as per the requirement and let me know if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to implement your own Tree Structure, as looks like your requirement is to maintain an explicit tree model yourself. For example,

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item>{

    private String name;
    private long timestamp;
    private List<Item> subItems = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public Item(String name, long timestamp){
        this.name = name;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public void addItem(Item subItem){
        this.subItems.add(subItem);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item o) {
        return Long.signum(this.timestamp - o.timestamp);
    }

}
```

If you want to get the item with largest or smallest timestamp or sort them, you can put all the items into a List and sort using `Collections.sort()` as you have implemented the Comparable interface.